# Select stmt in source qualifier along with procedure call in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have a situation where we are dealing with a relational source(Oracle). The system is developed in a way where we have to first execute a package which will enable data read from Oracle and user will be able to get results out of select statement. I am trying to find a way on how to implement this in informatica mapping.

What we tried

---

### **1. In PreSQL we tried to execute the package and in SQL query we wrote select statement - data not getting loaded in target.**

**2. In PreSQL we wrote a block in which we are executing the package and just after that(within same beging...end block) we wrote insert statement on top of select statement - This is inserting data through insert statement however I am not in favor of this solution as both source and target are dummy which will confuse people in future.**

Is there any possibility to  implement this solution somehow by using 1st option.

Please help and suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure transformation is there for this purpose configure it to execute source pre load

Answer (score 0):

Pre-Sql and data read are not a part of same session. From what I understand, this needs to be done within the same session as otherwise the read is granted only for the session.

What you can do, is create a stored procedure/package that will grant read access and then return the data. Use it as a SQL Override on your SQ. This way SQ will read the data as usual. The concept:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ReadMyData AS
BEGIN 
    execute immediate 'GiveMeTheReadAccess';
    select * from MyTable;
END;
```

And use the `ReadMyData` on the Source Qualifier.